# Using digest authentication for user login

Tags: php, codeigniter, digest

I am building an REST API using Phils RESTserver (PHP).
For the time being I am going to use Digest Authentication then oAuth.
Using Digest, one must supply username and password. Is it wrong to use
this authentication method to log users into the system rather than developers?

**User A:**

username = martin

password = passw0rd

**User B:**

username = mariah

password = LetMeIn

Comment: It is not wrong. If you use (and force) ssl connection then it's totally OK to use this authentication for your API.

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad, it's just not really maintainable or dynamic in any way so it's problematic. I've given you some advice on the oAuth provider problems in your other question so hopefully that will help, but I have never had my REST Server protected by oAuth.

Until a client pays me to implement it I have no interest in building it in! :D